# preg_match() grabs next line when subpattern subject is missing

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Have this pattern:

```
preg_match('/Artist:\s+(.*?)\n/i', $mp3info, $artist);
```

And this subject in $mp3info:

```
Format:  MPEG 1 Layer 3, Stereo
Details: 44100 Hz Stereo, 227 kbps, playtime 03:14
Tag:     ID3v2
Title:   
Artist:  
Album:   Latest
Year:    
Track:   
Genre:   
Comment: 
Encoder=
```

Works when Artist is not empty. When empty - $artist[1] returns the whole next line (Album).

Subject contains all white spaces and \n (Newlines).
Cannot use [A-Z], because information can be in any language.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch into [multiline mode](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) (`m`) and use [anchors](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.anchors.php) (`^`, `$`):

```
preg_match('/^Artist:[ \t]+(.*)$/mi', $mp3info, $artist);
```

```
$artist = $artist[1];
```

You also need to change `\s` to a character class (`[ \t]`), as the newline character was being eaten.

Comment: Tried multiline as well. Same result. /^Artist:\s+(.*?)$/im